# Jquery Form Validation Error Box Placement

Tags: jquery, jquery-form-validator

So, I am using formvalidator.net's jquery validation, but I am having a problem moving the error messages (shown how to here http://formvalidator.net/index.html#configuration_position).

I have followed it and it does not work, I have been trying to fix it for a while now and I cannot get it to work. My code is below. If it works, there should be an error box combining the two errors above the forms, like the below.[image: Like this]

I might be doing something incredibly stupid, but I am stuck.
Note: I tried using the snippet, but it doesn't work.

```js
$.validate({
  validateOnBlur: false, // disable validation when input looses focus
  errorMessagePosition: 'top' // Instead of 'element' which is default
  scrollToTopOnError: false // Set this property to true if you have a long form
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator/master/form-validator/theme-default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.2.8/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-validation="required">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" data-validation="required"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to move up the jquery library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.2.8/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
```

Because the `jquery.form-validator.min.js` file is written to use it with jQuery, you need to have jquery loaded before your validation plugin file.

Comment: Woops, well, in my code it's before the validator, when I was making the snippet, I guess I added it after. My main question still stands.